# SVG sprites gap issue

Tags: html, svg

I'm keen to figure out a good system for organising SVG's. [This](http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) seems really good, basically all my SVGs are in a file call SVGs.svg, which is included with PHP at the top of every page, then I use 'use' to display whichever one I want on the page.

SVGs.svg file:

```
<svg>
<defs>    
    <g id="MOlogo">

    ...

    </g>

    <g id="icon">

    ...

    </g>
</defs>
```

HTML to use an SVG:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use xlink:href="#MOlogo"></use>
</svg>
```

The trouble is, when I include the SVGs.svg file in my page I get a massive gap before the content of my page. Anyone know what might be causing that?

Cheers

Comment: could be that the aspect ratio of the icons is not 1:1. Difficult to tell since you've elided the icons themselves though. Providing a jsfiddle with actual icons would help,

Comment: I've just used css clip to hide it, seems to ok...